# Grunt JS how to target * all folders

Tags: javascript, selector, gruntjs

This src doesn't appear to target anything/returns nothing.

`src: ['docroot/components/*/*.js']`

rather than this

`src: ['docroot/components/pages/*.js', 'docroot/components/plugins/*.js']`

Is it possible to target random folders?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use double stars :
`src: ['docroot/components/**/*.js']`

Note the double star for folders. If you want to limit to one folder deep scanning you can use `src: ['docroot/components/{,*/}*.js']` this can help with performance if needed.

More on how to specify targets : [Gruntjs documentation - Configuring tasks : Globbing patterns](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns)